# When does Take get called in a linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

So I have something like this:

```
public IQueryable<Teachers> GetTeachers()
{
   var query = from a in this.Context.Techers
               where a.active == true
               select a
    return query;
}
```

Then I call it like this:

```
List<Teachers> =  this.repo.GetTeachers().Take(5000).ToList();
```

Let's say somewhere later in program I am marking those records active to false;

Now If I run this program again, should it return zero records? or does it pick "the next 5000 available" active records?

Comment: how many records are active?  I think if I am understanding your question it should take the next 5000 available

Comment: If you run this program **again** you will get next 5000 available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using LINQ to SQL (or LINQ to Entites), so your query is transformed in SQL query, which will look similar to this one:

```
SELECT TOP 5000 *
FROM techers
WHERE active = true
```

What will be returned depends on content of you table in db.

If you marked first 5000 records as inactive, running it again will return next 5000 active elements (if there still are active elements in your table).

Answer (score 1):

If you materialize the query into a list, it can't possibly be executed again against the server. List does not know anything about executing queries. Only if you keep the IQueryable around you can re-execute the query.